# What is the source code of the Python function intersection()

Tags: python, intersection

What is the source code of the Python function intersection()

i don't know where to find the code

Comment: what do you exactly mean? what is expected input and output? & what you have tried?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/search.html?q=intersection&check_keywords=yes&area=default

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

It's implemented in c.See the `set` implementation of the cpython source code：

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/135ec7cefbaffd516b77362ad2b2ad1025af462e/Objects/setobject.c